# Java Enum Constructor Undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

Why am i getting an error "Constructor is undefined" is it in my eclipse IDE? 
is there something wrong with my code?

```
public enum EnumHSClass {
    PALADIN ("Paladin"),ROUGE("ROUGE");
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the `("Paladin")` and `("ROUGE")` to mean?

Comment: i would want the PALADIN to have a string value of "Paladin". how could i get this kind of error where i think my syntax is right

Comment: its returning me "The constructor EnumHSClass(String) is undefined"

Comment: @Chizbox That is quite a useful error message I would say.

Comment: enum E { Palading, Rouge }; E.valueOf("Paladin").toString() might just do for a token with conversion to and from String.

Answer (score 13):

If you expect your enums to have parameters, you need to declare a constructor and fields for those parameters.

```
public enum EnumHSClass {
    PALADIN ("Paladin"),ROUGE("ROUGE");
    private final String name;
    private EnumHSClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a `constructor` in your enum like:

```
public enum EnumHSClass {

    PALADIN("Paladin"), ROUGE("ROUGE");

    String value;

    EnumHSClass(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

> Note: The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or
>   private access. It automatically creates the constants that are
>   defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum
>   constructor yourself.

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Note, the constructor is not allowed to be public.

Comment: @JamesB Yes, and there isn't any public modifier used in constructor here.

Answer (score 3):

Enums have constructors too, but only with either private or default visibility:

```
public enum EnumHSClass {
    PALADIN ("Paladin"),ROUGE("ROUGE");
    private EnumHSClass(String s) {
        // do something with s
    }
}
```

You may want to declare a field and create a getter for it, and set the field in the constructor.

Also note that the name of the enum instance is available for free via the (implicit) `name()` method that all enums have - maybe you can use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this:

```
public enum EnumHSClass {

    PALADIN ("Paladin"), ROUGE("ROUGE");

    private String name;

    private  EnumHSClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This will not compile.

Comment: For some reason I can't undo my downvote, even though you edited the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Days {
    MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2);
    int val;
    Days (int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```